# You don't have permission to access /php/send.php on this server 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, jquery, html

I get this error when trying to execute a php file when sending data from a html form here : http://imeji.es/connect.html

```
<form novalidate="" id="contact_form" name="contact_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="php/send.php">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                      <input type="email" placeholder="your email address" value="" name="email" id="email">
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                      <input type="subject" placeholder="subject" value="" name="subject" id="subject">
                                    </li>                                    
                                    <li>
                                      <!--label for="message">Message:</label-->
                                      <textarea placeholder="your message" name="message" class="message" id="msg" cols="40" rows="10" title="your message"></textarea>
                                     <div class="center-element-wrap">
                                <div class="center-element">
                                  <input type="submit" value="send" class="submit btn">
                              </div>
                           </div> 
                                    </li>
                                 </ul>
                            </form>
```

I don't understand why this is happening, could it be a server problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do from the command line on a Linux machine:

```
chmod 755 send.php
```

if it doesn't allow you to change the permissions you might have to do:

```
sudo chmod 755 send.php
```

Comment: I did this with the ftp client, changing the properties to 755. Didn't help

Comment: You can try 777 and see if that works